# Updating a Prims algorithm for Minimum spanning trees

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm

I need help doing a c++ or java method that prints a minimum spanning tree but also prints the minimum spanning tree without all of the vertices that are in the graph. So basically if the min span tree has weight 37 then the min span tree without some edge a to b has weight 49, and  next tree with out edge b to c has  weight 50.

So the question is, how can i take out arbitrary edges of the MST and calculate a new one without that edge with minimal time complexity.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for this site. You should search for some code somewhere else and come back with specific questions if you have difficulty getting it to work. If you already have code, then show enough to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I would recommend trying your luck on http://cs.stackexchange.com/, or http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/. It sounds like those sites would be better suited to your question.

Comment: This is called "decremental minimum spanning tree" in the CS literature. There are also algorithms specifically for computing the top-k spanning trees if that's what you're ultimately trying to do.